# Discrete mathematics - venn diagram logic

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, arithmetic

[image]An anonymous survey of college students that determined their behaviors regarding alcohol, cigs, and illegal drugs. Results:

- 894 drank alcohol regularly
- 192 used illegal drugs
- 114 drank alcohol regularly and used illegal drugs
- 97 engaged in all three behaviors
- 665 smoked cigs
- 424 drank alcohol regularly and smoked cigs
- 119 smoked cigs and used illegal drugs
- 309 engaged in none of the behaviors

> a) find the number of students in the survey
>
> b) find the number of students who engaged in exactly two of these these behaviors

I drew a venn diagram for this question.

- part a) I used all the students used in this diagram, it is incorrect.
- part b) I subtracted what I did for a by the number of students who did two or more.

> both of these parts are incorrect I believe.

Comment: Can you show your Venn diagram?  It would be easier to check your work if we could see it.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang sure thing, added picture

Comment: Alcohol and drugs *without* cigarettes is not 114.  It is 114 - 97. It is *all* Alcohol and drugs - alcohol and drugs *AND* cigarettes.  Alcohol and cigarettes *without* drugs is not 424.  It is 424 - 97. It is *all* Alcohol and cigarettes - alcohol and cigarettes *AND* drugs. cigarettes and drugs *without* alcohol is not 119.  It is 119 - 97. It is *all* cigaretts and drugs - cigarettes and drugs *AND* alcohol.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 114 write 114-97=17 similarly for all others except 97 that is correct.

See the question says that 114 drank alcohol regularly and that will include the intersection of three circles also.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Is it clear now?

Comment: no... like I said, I thought what I did was correct but I got marked off big time for having incorrect response and diagram

Comment: your diagram is wrong like i said one who is engaged in all three behaviour also drank alcohol regularly and used illegal drugs so instead of 114 you should write 17.

Comment: The 97 who did all three are *included* in the 114 that did alcohol and drugs.  There are 114 who did alcohol and drugs and maybe they did cigarettes and maybe they didn't.  There are are 97 who did alcohol and drugs and cigarettes.  That means there were 114 -97=17who did drugs and alcohol be did not do cigarettes.   You wrote it as 114.

Answer (score 0):

Your Venn diagram is divided into eight segments:

Let $D$ be the segment of people that *only* do drugs.  They do not do alcohol or cigarettes.  You've written that as $192$.  That is wrong.  $192$ is *everybody* who does drugs whether or not they do alcohol or cigarettes.  Six of your eight segments are wrong.

Let $AD$ be the segment of people that do alcohol and drugs but not cigarettes.

Let $A$ be the segment of people that do only alcohol.

Let $DC$ be the segment of people that do drugs and alcohol only.

Let $ADC$ be the segment of people that do all three.  This is the only internal segment you did right.

Let $AC$ be the segment of people that do Alochol and cigarettes only.

Let $C$  be the segment of people that did only cigarettes.

Let $X$ be the segment of the people that did none.  You did that one right.

"894 drank alcohol regularly".  That means $A + AD + AC + ADC= 894$

"192 used illegal drugs" That means $D + AD + DC + ADC = 192$

"114 drank alcohol regularly and used illegal drugs" That means $AD + ADC = 114$.

"97 engaged in all three behaviors" That means $ADC = 97$

"665 smoked cigs" That means $C + AC + DC + ADC = 665$

"424 drank alcohol regularly and smoked cigs" That means $AC + ADC = 424$

"119 smoked cigs and used illegal drugs" That means $DC + ADC = 119$

"309 engaged in none of the behaviors" That means $X = 309$.

Now redo the entire thing.

=====

```
894 drank alcohol regularly
192 used illegal drugs
114 drank alcohol regularly and used illegal drugs
97 engaged in all three behaviors
665 smoked cigs
424 drank alcohol regularly and smoked cigs
119 smoked cigs and used illegal drugs
309 engaged in none of the behaviors
```

Your mistake was in calculationg $|A \cap D \cap C^c| = 114$.  You assumed incorrectly that $A \cap D$ (those who do Alcohol and Drugs) and  $A \cap D \cap C^c$ (those who do Alcohol and Drugs *only*; no cigarettes) where the same.  They are not.

$A \cap D \cap C^c \subset A \cap D$ and $A \cap D = (A \cap D \cap C) \cup (A \cap D \cap C^c)$

So $|A \cap D| = |A \cap D \cap C| + |A \cap D \cap C^c| - |(A \cap D \cap C) \cap (A \cap D \cap C^c)|$

$114 = 97 + |A \cap D \cap C^c| + |\emptyset|$

$|A \cap D \cap C^c| = 17$.

That was your entire problem.  But you didn't have to break the entire venn diagram down, if you use the inclusion/exclusion principle.

($|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B|$ which can inductively extended to $|A \cup B \cup C| = |A|+|B| +|C| - |A \cap B|-|A \cap C|-|B \cap C|+|A \cap B\cap C|$)

$|A| = 894$

$|D| = 192$

$|A \cap D| = 114$

[This means $|A \cup D| = |A| + |D| - |A\cap D| =894 + 192 - 114 = 927$ just in case that is ever asked...]

$|A \cap D \cap C| = 97$

$|C| = 665$

$|A \cap C| = 424$

$|C \cap D| = 119$

$|(A \cup C \cup D)^c| = 309$

All students = $|A \cup C \cup D| + |(A \cup C \cup D)^c|$

$|(A \cup C \cup D)^c| = 309$

$|A \cup C \cup D| = |A| + |C| + |D| - |A \cap C| - |A \cap D| - |C \cap D| + |A \cap C \cap D|$

$|A| = 894; |C|=665; |D|=192; |A \cap C|=424; |A \cap D| = 114; |C \cap D|=119;|A \cap C \cap D| = 97$

So students are $309 + 894 + 665 + 192 - 424 - 114 - 119 + 97$.

To figure out how many engaged in exactly two you do:

=====

People who engage in exactly two = people engaged in at least to minus those engage in all three.

Those in A and D only are $|A \cap D| - |A \cap D \cap C|=114-97 = 17$

Those in A and C only are $|A \cap C| - |A \cap D \cap C| =424 - 97 = 327$

Those in D and C only are $|D \cap C|- |A\cap D\cap C| = 119 - 97 = 22$

So those in exactly two are $17+327 + 22$.

Comment: I'm still confused, is my diagram correct?

Comment: No.  As I said You have$ |A∩D∩C^c|=114$ when it should be 17.  So, no, your diagram is *not* correct.

Comment: so changing 114 to 17 would make it correct? which is what vinayak is saying?

Comment: Actually, all three of your intersections are wrong.  You are confusing A and B (whether or not C) with A and B and definitely not C.

Comment: Actually your diagram is *completely* wrong.  You are putting the total of EVERY group in the smallest spots.  Example: 192 = *EVERYBODY* who does drugs whether or not they did cigs or alcohol.  You put 192 in the section for people who *ONLY* do drugs.  And so on.  192 has to include not just that segment but also the drugs and cig segment and the drugs and alcohol segment and the all three segment.

Comment: 192 is everybody who does drugs whether or not they do alcohol or cigarettes. Six of your eight segments are wrong. So we are assuming everyone is underage?